# Can table initialization be sped up in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to construct semantic similarity search using [Google's universal sentence encoder](http://%22https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2%22) from the Tensorflow hub, which from my knowledge takes lowercase tokenized string and outputs 512 embedding vector.

## Main Problem

Everything but the table initialization process is performed under a second:

```
session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer()) # performed less than a second
session.run(tf.tables_initializer()) # takes 15+ seconds
```

The line above takes ~20 seconds, Is there any way of speeding table initialization process (so that later, for practical use, it quickly transforms user input to embedding vector)?

---

Code is quite simple:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import pickle # just for saving vectorized data

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # avoid any logs but error

embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")

def search_converted(query_text, file_path="file_path"):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # initialize global variables
        session.run(tf.tables_initializer())  # initialize tables
        message_embeddings = session.run(embed([query_text])) # turn query text into vector embeddings
    similarities = []  # array of similarities (float values)
    with open(file_path, "rb") as fl:  # open pickle containing array that contains vector embeddings and their readable form
        pckl = pickle.load(fl)
        for col in pckl[0]: # vector embeddings
            similarities.append(1 - acos(np.inner(message_embeddings[0], col) / (
                        np.linalg.norm(message_embeddings[0]) * np.linalg.norm(col))) / pi)   # append angular distance similarities to array
    return (pckl[1][similarities.index(max(similarities))], max(similarities))   # return the most similar string, with the similarity precentage
```

Code above is just for testing (I know it is not optimal in practice). It opens pickled file containing arrays and from those arrays it chooses the most similar string.

---

Shortly, how  can I speed up table initialization so that I use this library in practice?

Comment: Have you checked it is the variables and not actually the tables ?

Comment: @P-Gn Apologies, I didn't consider that possibility. It was actually tables, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Did you try checking it with latest versions of TF Hub and latest versions of USE and check if the issue still persists. Also, if possible, please use Tensorflow Version 2.0. Thanks!